# Creating a series of SQLite tables from a list of classes

Tags: c#, sqlite, reflection, system.reflection

I have generated a list of public classes that need to be added into an SQLite database.

I get the class names like this

```
private List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
...
var pathName = Directory.GetFiles(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dirPath) ? "SQLClasses" : dirPath);
foreach (var path in pathName)
    types.AddRange(Assembly.LoadFrom(path).GetTypes());
```

types now contains my classes that need to be turned into SQLite tables.

Normally, I would create my tables like this

```
using (SQLiteConnection sqlCon = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
{
     sqlCon.CreateTable<TableName>();
```

As I already have my list of classes held in types, I'm trying to insert these tables into the database using a simple foreach

Currently I have this

```
foreach(var t in types)
{
    var T = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    sqlCon.CreateTable<T>();
}
```

neither this nor the simpler

```
sqlCon.CreateTable<typeof(t)>();
```

or

```
sqlCon.CreateTable<t>();
```

work (all three give T [or t] doesn't exist in the current context)

Can I use this simple foreach method to insert the table names or do I have to do something more complex?

Comment: I could not find a method  `CreateTable` neither in the docs [system.data.sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/)  nor in the docs [microsoft.data.sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite?view=msdata-sqlite-3.1.0). What am i missing?

Comment: `CreateTable` is available in [SQLite-net library](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that CreateTable has two overloaded methods

```
sqlCon.CreateTable<T>();
```

and

```
sqlCon.CreateTable(t);
```

the second allowing for a type to be used rather than a generic class of T to be used. I was unaware of this second method until I noticed some obscure reference on a website than mentioned a second method but failed to say what it was. Digging around found this.

My apologies for not providing a fuller answer earlier

Comment: If this is the answer, then explain how this works. This answer has already been flagged as low quality, and will be deleted if not edited soon.